# C# app to select data from MySQL and insert to SQL-server (blob files)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server-2008, blob, openrowset

I want to run a query on a MySQL database and insert the results in a SQL-Server 2008 R2 database.

In my table (MySQL database) there are multiple columns and one of them contains a file path. I want to use that path to insert the actual file as BLOB in my SQL-server.

So all columns from MySQL need to be inserted in SQL-server and the actual file as BLOB.

I can connect and query the MySQL database and also connect my SQL-Server.
But how can i insert the results. (some files are very large !!)

I found someting about OPENROWSET, but i could not find a good example inserting the metadata **and** the file.

I want to write a C# app for this. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

SQL-Server 2008 R2 Support file stream. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx)

BLOBs can be standard varbinary(max) data that stores the data in tables
FILESTREAM varbinary(max) objects that store the data in the file system
If Objects that are being stored are, on average, larger than 1 MB you shoul go with filestream.

Comment: Filestream is not enabled. Because it's not 'my' server i can't enable it. Another suggestion.

Comment: We have no choice. If you try to put files blob in to db. I think a good way to upload or save file as chuck to save memory consumes ion.  There is a good staple at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3517w44b(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thx. Maybe you can help me with an error in my exampe. My ID is a UniqueIdentifier. So i changed "SqlParameter idParm = addEmp.Parameters.Add("@Identity", SqlDbType.Int);
            idParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
to SqlParameter idParm = addRec.Parameters.Add("@Identity", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                idParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; My error message: Operand type clash: numeric is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

Answer (score 0):

As @Pongsathon.keng mentioned in his response FileStream is an option.  You need to enable your DB to support FileStream and the user that is writing cannot be a sql login (Keep that in mind).  You can use a varbinary(max) also mentioned (Image will be deprecated).

We decided to go with FileStream so we could also utilize it in conjunction with FUll-Text Indexing.  You could also go with the typical "Store File Path" approach and store the actual files / blogs in a file system.  FileStream gives you the added benefit of backing up files with the DB and apply permissions / transactions, etc.

Really depends on what you are doing.

Some good articles on FileStream [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724.aspx) and [Here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/)